# Logical data model - how to indicate optional FK?

Tags: entity-relationship, data-modeling

If a logical data model is modelling entities with optional foreign keys, how is that indicated on the model? I'm looking at one now, where, for example, we have:

```
COUNTRY 1:1 ----------- 0:N TRANSACTION
```

The TRANSACTION entity contains a country attribute that may or may not have a value. I would have thought that in this case, the optionality of the FK would be shown as:

```
COUNTRY 0:1 ----------- 0:N TRANSACTION
```

Is that correct? Or does the 1:1 also imply "IFF a value is provided"?

Comment: Logical data models don't model entities, that's conceptual data modeling. Logical data models model predicates.

Comment: OK, I have a data model that contains the types of elements as listed under "Logical" here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30982457/6923771, including attributes, PKs and FKs. I was wondering about the way an optional FK should be depicted in such a model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that you're correct. If a TRANSACTION has an optional association with a COUNTRY, then using min-max notation we would indicate

```
COUNTRY 0:1 ----------- 0:N TRANSACTION
```

`1:1` doesn't imply "IFF a value is provided", it explicitly states a value must be provided.